# Invalid session/connection in Openfire

Tags: java, openfire, hazelcast

We are running an openfire server with hazelcast plugin for clustering. Sometimes the client IP shows as null or Invalid session/connection in the XMPP Console, as shown in the image and when this is shown the clients get disconnected, and are never able to reconnect [image: Invalid session]

The warn.log file shows:

> 2016.10.05 23:45:36 org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.ConnectionHandler - Closing connection due to exception in session: (0x0002298E: nio
>   socket, server, null => 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:5222)
>   org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolDecoderException:
>   org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.XMLNotWellFormedException: Character is
>   invalid in: ^V (Hexdump: 16 03 03 00 96 10 00 00 92 91 04 01 AC EF A4
>   1F 6D 28 E6 B0 99 33 B2 D6 87 2C 1B B1 DF 77 1E 1D D7 FB E5 47 7D 04
>   8A 5E B8 77 59 FA 31 80 68 BA C0 8C C8 A9 7E A0 7D 74 2D 68 EF E0 B1
>   35 32 05 1D EA 97 2B 27 CB A9 D8 38 6F C0 59 0C B4 AB AC 33 90 09 05
>   38 18 97 EC 6F 97 1E 7B 09 56 FD A8 CC B3 2B 15 CA 22 9B 8E 02 84 25
>   9F E7 90 72 2A 7D 84 12 10 4C 58 21 10 E6 C3 77 03 79 F0 4D 7C 7C 15
>   4C BD AD 24 72 7D B7 CD AD 53 4B 2F BF 3F AD E7 F0 D5 A4 2C 55 36 84
>   D0 74 14 03 03 00 01 01 16 03 03 00 40 95 06 24 78 2F 4A 9C 0D 92 22
>   EB 32 2A 03 13 35 4A 5A E6 44 2B 31 D7 48 99 4A BC AF 32 BE F5 D3 22
>   09 92 E2 1C 9E 14 EA 3D 76 93 31 D8 45 A1 D8 FB 46 E2 BD C6 42 59 E4
>   5B C2 24 73 77 01 DA 95)
>           at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:242)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:417)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:765)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:74)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.session.IoEvent.run(IoEvent.java:63)
>           at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:769)
>           at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTasks(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:761)
>           at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:703)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.XMLNotWellFormedException: Character is
>   invalid in: ^V
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.XMLLightweightParser.read(XMLLightweightParser.java:223)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.XMPPDecoder.doDecode(XMPPDecoder.java:41)
>           at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.CumulativeProtocolDecoder.decode(CumulativeProtocolDecoder.java:176)
>           at org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter.messageReceived(ProtocolCodecFilter.java:232)
>           ... 9 more
>
> 2016.10.05 23:46:51 com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.ReadHandler - [172.31.29.146]:5701 [openfire] [3.5.1] hz.openfire.IO.thread-in-0
>   Closing socket to endpoint Address[172.31.20.168]:5701,
>   Cause:java.io.EOFException: Remote socket closed!
>   2016.10.05 23:46:52 com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionMonitor - [172.31.29.146]:5701 [openfire] [3.5.1] Removing connection to
>   endpoint Address[172.31.20.168]:5701 Cause => java.net.SocketException
>   {Connection refused to address /172.31.20.168:5701}, Error-Count: 5
>   2016.10.05 23:46:57 com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.ReadHandler - [172.31.29.146]:5701 [openfire] [3.5.1] hz.openfire.IO.thread-in-1
>   Closing socket to endpoint Address[172.31.29.47]:5701,
>   Cause:java.io.EOFException: Remote socket closed!
>   2016.10.05 23:46:58 com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionMonitor - [172.31.29.146]:5701 [openfire] [3.5.1] Removing connection to
>   endpoint Address[172.31.29.47]:5701 Cause => java.net.SocketException
>   {Connection refused to address /172.31.29.47:5701}, Error-Count: 5
>   2016.10.05 23:46:59 com.hazelcast.map.impl.BasicMapContextQuerySupport - [172.31.29.146]:5701 [openfire] [3.5.1] Could not get results java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetNotMemberException: Not Member!
>   target:Address[172.31.29.47]:5701, partitionId: -1, operation:
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.QueryOperation, service:
>   hz:impl:mapService
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveApplicationResponseOrThrowException(InvocationFuture.java:357)
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.get(InvocationFuture.java:225)
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.get(InvocationFuture.java:204)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.BasicMapContextQuerySupport.addResultsOfPredicate(BasicMapContextQuerySupport.java:350)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.BasicMapContextQuerySupport.query(BasicMapContextQuerySupport.java:249)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.query(MapProxySupport.java:1136)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.entrySet(MapProxyImpl.java:575)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.entrySet(MapProxyImpl.java:560)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.plugin.util.cache.ClusteredCache.entrySet(ClusteredCache.java:117)
>           at org.jivesoftware.util.cache.CacheWrapper.entrySet(CacheWrapper.java:130)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.RoutingTableImpl.leftCluster(RoutingTableImpl.java:1065)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.cluster.ClusterManager$2.run(ClusterManager.java:118)
>   Caused by: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetNotMemberException: Not
>   Member! target:Address[172.31.29.47]:5701, partitionId: -1, operation:
>   com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.QueryOperation, service:
>   hz:impl:mapService
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.initInvocationTarget(Invocation.java:298)
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:222)
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.run(Invocation.java:262)
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.TargetInvocation.run(TargetInvocation.java:29)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>           at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
>           at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
>           at ------ End remote and begin local stack-trace ------.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveApplicationResponse(InvocationFuture.java:384)
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveApplicationResponseOrThrowException(InvocationFuture.java:334)
>           ... 11 more
>
> 2016.10.05 23:47:01 com.hazelcast.spi.EventService - [172.31.29.146]:5701 [openfire] [3.5.1] Error while logging processing
>   event java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.jivesoftware.util.StringUtils.getBytes(StringUtils.java:1098)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.plugin.util.cache.CacheListener.handleEntryEvent(CacheListener.java:68)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.plugin.util.cache.CacheListener.entryRemoved(CacheListener.java:60)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapListenerAdaptors$2$1.onEvent(MapListenerAdaptors.java:83)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.InternalMapListenerAdapter.onEvent(InternalMapListenerAdapter.java:51)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapEventPublishingService.callListener(MapEventPublishingService.java:90)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapEventPublishingService.dispatchEntryEventData(MapEventPublishingService.java:102)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapEventPublishingService.dispatchEvent(MapEventPublishingService.java:46)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapEventPublishingService.dispatchEvent(MapEventPublishingService.java:33)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapService.dispatchEvent(MapService.java:91)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapService.dispatchEvent(MapService.java:61)
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.eventservice.impl.EventPacketProcessor.process(EventPacketProcessor.java:53)
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.eventservice.impl.RemoteEventPacketProcessor.run(RemoteEventPacketProcessor.java:38)
>           at com.hazelcast.util.executor.StripedExecutor$Worker.process(StripedExecutor.java:190)
>           at com.hazelcast.util.executor.StripedExecutor$Worker.run(StripedExecutor.java:174)

The error.log shows

> 2016.10.05 23:47:13 org.jivesoftware.openfire.SessionManager - Could not close socket
>   com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast
>   instance is not active!
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.AbstractDistributedObject.getService(AbstractDistributedObject.java:93)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.toData(MapProxySupport.java:1122)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.remove(MapProxyImpl.java:178)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.plugin.util.cache.ClusteredCache.remove(ClusteredCache.java:96)
>           at org.jivesoftware.util.cache.CacheWrapper.remove(CacheWrapper.java:145)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.RoutingTableImpl.removeClientRoute(RoutingTableImpl.java:903)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.SessionManager.removeSession(SessionManager.java:1234)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.SessionManager.removeSession(SessionManager.java:1206)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.SessionManager$ClientSessionListener.onConnectionClose(SessionManager.java:1409)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.NIOConnection.notifyCloseListeners(NIOConnection.java:260)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.NIOConnection.close(NIOConnection.java:242)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.ConnectionHandler.exceptionCaught(ConnectionHandler.java:161)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.exceptionCaught(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:672)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextExceptionCaught(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:461)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1100(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.exceptionCaught(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:760)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.exceptionCaught(IoFilterAdapter.java:102)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextExceptionCaught(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:461)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1100(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.exceptionCaught(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:760)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.exceptionCaught(IoFilterAdapter.java:102)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextExceptionCaught(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:461)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1100(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.exceptionCaught(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:760)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterEvent.fire(IoFilterEvent.java:93)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.session.IoEvent.run(IoEvent.java:63)
>           at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:769)
>           at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTasks(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:761)
>           at org.apache.mina.filter.executor.OrderedThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(OrderedThreadPoolExecutor.java:703)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   2016.10.05 23:47:13 org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.ConnectionHandler - Closing connection due to error while processing message: dXNlcm5hbWU9Ijk2NjUwNDgxMTkxOCIscmVhbG09InhtcHAuc2F5ZmVhcHAuY29tIixjbm9uY2U9ImY2MmM2OWMxOGU4ZWEzM2Y5NmRhY2I0ODU4YzhiNTQwNWU0ZDRiMzVmM2U4NWNmNjk0OGJmNWE5M2Q0MDAzNmIiLG5jPTAwMDAwMDAxLHFvcD1hdXRoLGRpZ2VzdC11cmk9InhtcHAveG1wcC5zYXlmZWFwcC5jb20iLHJlc3BvbnNlPTY3ODQ0MDM0ZjA5ZDc4YzQyODFmN2E1YzhmMGMyNDFhLGNoYXJzZXQ9dXRmLTgsbm9uY2U9IlpCME1CUVBwNFZsT2RxTWhIZTQwcWIxTHh4b1NoNkZwRDhRaXZKUm4i
>   com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast
>   instance is not active!
>           at com.hazelcast.spi.AbstractDistributedObject.getService(AbstractDistributedObject.java:93)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.toData(MapProxySupport.java:1122)
>           at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.get(MapProxyImpl.java:81)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.plugin.util.cache.ClusteredCache.get(ClusteredCache.java:92)
>           at org.jivesoftware.util.cache.CacheWrapper.get(CacheWrapper.java:140)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.lockout.LockOutManager.getUserLockOut(LockOutManager.java:244)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.lockout.LockOutManager.getDisabledStatus(LockOutManager.java:152)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.lockout.LockOutManager.isAccountDisabled(LockOutManager.java:163)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.SASLAuthentication.authenticationSuccessful(SASLAuthentication.java:682)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.SASLAuthentication.handle(SASLAuthentication.java:357)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.StanzaHandler.process(StanzaHandler.java:191)
>           at org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.ConnectionHandler.messageReceived(ConnectionHandler.java:180)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:690)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextMessageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:417)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$1200(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.messageReceived(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:765)
>           at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.messageReceived(IoFilterAdapter.java:109)

Kindly help me with this. Thanks!

Regards,
Iqbal

Comment: Logs are stating that for some unknown reason, cluster breaks. Have you tried to identify that? Like when this happens, what is shown in Clustering section? Provide screenshot of that too.

Comment: @ShoaibAhmadGondal clustering section in openfire console shows all the clusters properly. I didn't find any other issue in logs or console. Also didn't get the reason for session turning null in the cache.

Comment: What's the frequency of this message in logs:
[172.31.29.146]:5701 [openfire] [3.5.1] Removing connection to endpoint Address[172.31.20.168]:5701

Also these are 29.146 logs, what about 20.168 logs at the same time?

Comment: These errors happen every one to two seconds. And all the servers shall have the Removing connection to end point address error at the same time.